MSAL and JWT, how to handle multiple audiences either at client or server?
I'm struggling with communicating 2 .NET Core APIs which use Azure AD (Entra) to authenticate the JWT bearers from the requests they receive. In particular, I'm trying to use the approach described in here to get a JWT token from our Entra server using a Client Secret and a TenantId. This I can get with no problem, but when I try to use it to communicate with my other application, I get a 401 Unauthorized response. Here's a quick, horrible sketch:

The second API is configured like:
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
 {
     options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
 }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
 {
     options.Authority = configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:Authority");
 });

services.AddOptions<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .Configure<IConfiguration>((options, configuration) =>
    {
        configuration.GetSection("Authentication").Bind(options);
    });

services.AddAuthorization();

With this, in theory I'm setting both the Authority and the Audience. This works fine when communicating from the Frontend (a third app) using the token we get when logging in using MS login, but with the token I get using the ConfidentialClientApplication instance I get the 401. This is a Class I created to handle the Token acquiring:
public class ConfidentialClient : IConfidentialClient
{
    private readonly AzureADOptions _ADOConfig;
    
    // This object will cache tokens in-memory - keep it as a singleton
    private readonly IConfidentialClientApplication clientApp;

    public ConfidentialClient(IOptions<AzureADOptions> options) 
    {
        this._ADOConfig = options.Value;
        this.clientApp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_ADOConfig.ClientId)
            .WithClientSecret(_ADOConfig.ClientCredentials.First().ClientSecret)
            .Build();
    }

    public async Task<string> GetToken()
    {
        // When making the request, specify the tenant-based authority
        var authResult = await this.clientApp.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes: new[] { _ADOConfig.Scopes.First() })
                .WithTenantId(_ADOConfig.TenantId)
                .ExecuteAsync();

        return authResult.AccessToken;
    }
}

Token I can get just fine, but the API is rejecting it. While comparing the 2 tokens, one of the main differences I can see is the Audience, the one set on the token I get from the ConfidentialClient looks generic and different from the one configured on the receiving app's JWT authentication strategy (and the token used by the frontend), and I think the token is getting rejected because of that.
Is there a way of configuring a specific Audience for the ConfidentialClient, or have the JWTBearer Authentication strategy configured in a way that it can accept multiple audiences?

I had a test before and you might take a look at this case. I didn't face your issue before. Make sure that your configurations are correct, the appsettings in the API project should set the client ID which is the same with the client id you used in your frontend app, and this app in Azure should be added the correct API permission, Then for the audience field, you should set as the client id which is exposing the API. Then the APi would validate the access token generated by the frontend app.

I'm not very understand what you are trying to achieve but based on your architecture picture, it looks like that you are having a frontend client app which allowing users to sign in, and it will generate access token for you used to call backend server API. In the meantime, you have 2 APIs protected by Azure AD. This is a common scenario, however you are trying to use client credential flow(according to the link you shared in the question) to generate access token which is designed for daemon application instead of your scenario.
Per my understanding, you might have 2 or 3 Azure AD applications, one for the frontend app used to authentication, 1 or 2 apps for exposing API and used as scope parameter for generating access token to call the 2 APIs. You can take a look at this document to enable AAD protection for your API project, which is a little different than the code snippets you shared.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

This is what you should have in Program.cs. You can create a new API project using VS template but please choose Microsoft Identity Platform as the authentication type, and you will have all required configuration and codes directly, so that you could see what are required.
==============================
using Azure.Identity;

var scopes = new[] { "api://expose_api_client_id/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "your_azuread_clientid_which_granted_api_permission";
var clientSecret = "corresponding_client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(scopes);
var token = clientSecretCredential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext).Result.Token;


Hey, hi Wang, thanks for the reply. Yeah, for simplicity's sake I mentioned these as APIs, the API work just fine, what I'm having trouble with is an Azure Function Application which needs to communicate with one of these APIs using a JWT, the frontend applications gets the JWT from Entra using the interactive login and a user account. What I need is to get a JWT in the Azure Function from the Entra server, I managed to get one with Client Secret but the JWT's data is different from the one I get in the frontend, specifically the Audience is different and I thought that might be the problem

Thanks for your confirmation! Then I'm afraid that you are trying to get  an access token in the Azure function. And that's true Azure function is a kind of daemon application which could use client credential flow to generate an access token, but it requires Application type of API permission, you should follow this section. Then please try my codes updated in your function to generate the access token.

Thanks again Wang! We managed to work around the issue by providing the audience of the Authentication configuration (in API 2) into the scopes parameter of AcquireTokenForClient, but your solution looks cleaner, I'll try it out

Thank you for your kind reply and please feel free to let me if it worked or not : )
